# AngularJS changing dropdown value with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropdown, angular-ngmodel

```
nameList contains [“Julia”, “Evan”, “Tomas”];

select ng-model=“names” ng-options=“x for x in nameList”
```

In controller, I have a service api call `GetNameByID/{id}”`and depending on the `id`, I want to initialize the dropdown value of the modal form.

So if the user clicks `ID` 1, the dropdown defaults to *Julia*.

The problem is within the service call, when I try to initialize the model by doing `$scope.names = data`, it adds an empty option at the top instead of selecting *Julia*. When I `console.log(data)`, it prints *“Julia”* but it becomes `<option value=“?”></option>`

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So Lets have a HTML example for this case:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="names" ng-options="item for item in nameList">
    </select>

    <p>Selected : {{names}}</p>

    <button ng-click="Update(2)"> Update(1)</button> 
</div>
```

and Conrtoller has  one service  call which update your dropdown accordingly based on index.

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.names = "Julia"
    $scope.nameList =  ["Julia", "Evan", "Tomas"]; 

    $scope.Update = function(_value){ 
        $scope.names = $scope.nameList[ parseInt(_value)] ;
    }
}
```

Please have a look into running code, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9vbrLn0/11/).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `ng-init` to initialize the dropdown first value like so:

```
<select ng-model="names" ng-init="names = data[0]" ng-options="x for x in data">
    <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

Where `[0]` in `data[0]` is the position of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where you can set the option

In html file

```
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in nameList"></select>
```

In js file

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
var id = 1;

$scope.names = ["Julia", "Evan", "Tomas"];
$scope.selectedName = $scope.names[id-1];    <---- here you can pass you id.
});
```

subtract id with 1 because array start with 0. Hope this is what you want to acheive.